# Replacing one character in a string by its index in Delphi?

Tags: string, delphi

I've tried the following code without success.

```
string.remove[index];
string.insert[index];
```

Can anyone suggest how can I correct this code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just do this:

```
stringVariable[index] := 'A';
```

Comment: It's valid for most of delphi, but that kind of code now is depricated. If you need to change string, you must use TStringBuilder class for that kind of work.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: it is not deprecated just yet, but it may be in the not-too-distant future. The current version already issues warnings about it now.

Comment: @Remy: I just tested in XE4, with `Test := 'Testing'; Test[3] := 'x'; WriteLn(Test); ReadLn;`, and don't get any compiler warning in a Win32 console app.

Comment: It is not deprecated in the Windows/OSX compilers yet, but it is deprecated in the iOS mobile compiler [and documented as such](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Migrating_Delphi_Code_to_iOS_from_Desktop): "the Delphi mobile compilers emit the warning **W1068 Modifying strings in place may not be supported in the future (Delphi)**. At some point, this warning is to be replaced by an error"

Answer (score 7):

You can directly access a string like it was a character array in Delphi:

```
MyString[Index] := NewChar;
```

For multiple character deletions and inserts, the `System` unit provides `Delete` and `Insert`:

```
System.Delete(MyString, Index, NumChars);
System.Insert(NewChars, MyString, Index);
```

Recent versions of Delphi provide the helper functions to `string`:

```
MyString := MyString.Remove(3, 1);
MyString := MyString.Insert(3, NewChars);
```

Once again, please read the tutorials I've referred you to twice previously. This is a very basic Pascal question that any of them would have answered for you.

Comment: I TRIED and compiler gives me fail!

Comment: @Diego no it does not "give you fail!" - it gives you a specific error message, which you should READ and post in your original question if you don't understand!

Comment: Would the downvoter please explain what's wrong with my answer, both so I can correct it and so I can see the problem? Thanks.

Comment: @David: Not that important, and usually I just ignore them. I actually thought I'd covered the bases pretty well here, though, so I was just curious what I'd missed. I still don't see anything wrong, so it's most likely either someone being extremely petty or someone getting revenge for something.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to do it. Have fun with Delphi

```
FUNCTION ReplaceCharInPos(CONST Text: String; Ch: Char; P: Integer): String;
VAR Lng: Integer; left, Right: String;
BEGIN
  Lng:= Length(Text);
  IF Lng = 0 THEN
    Result:= ''
  ELSE IF (P < 1) OR (P > Lng) THEN
    Result:= Text
  ELSE IF P = 1 THEN
    Result:= Ch + Copy(Text, 2, Lng - 1)
  ELSE IF P = Lng THEN
    Result:= Copy(Text, 1, Lng - 1) + Ch
  ELSE BEGIN
    Left:=  Copy(Text, 1, P - 1);
    Right:= Copy(Text, P + 1, Lng - P);
    Result:= Left + Ch + Right;
  END;
END;
```